# How to use two MongoDB aggregations to perform an updateMany

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am trying to write a script that uses 2 aggregates and saves the results as an array to be used for an `updateMany`.

The first `aggregate` finds any documents that has a `firstTrackingId` and a `secondTrackingId` on it. I save this into an array. This aggregate is working correctly when tested alone.

The second `aggregate` will use the first aggregate's result array, pulling all documents that have a `firstTrackingId` from the first aggregate's results. This one will pull any documents that do NOT have a `secondTrackingId` on it, and save the unique mongo `_id`/`ObjectId` to an array.

The `updateMany` will use all of the results from the second aggregation to update all relevant documents with a status of void.

All these functions are working when I give them hard-coded data, but I can't figure out how to pull the data from the arrays. I am not even sure if I'm "saving" it correctly, or if there  is something else  I should be doing aside from just initializing the aggregation as an array.

```
var ids = db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "firstTrackingId": { "$ne": "" },
            "secondTrackingId": { "$exists": true }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$firstTrackingId",
        }
    },
])


var secondIds = db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "firstTrackingId": { $in: ids },
            "secondTrackingId": { $exists: false }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
        }
    },
])


db.getCollection('Test').updateMany({
    "_id": {
        "$in": secondIds
    },
}, { $set: {
        "status": "VOID"
    } })
```

I tried printing the first aggregation's results out... can't really figure out how... so for the first one if I do:

```
print(ids.next(ids._id))
```

I get:

```
[object BSON]
```

Which leads me to believe I need to somehow perform an `$objectToArray`. If anyone has any insight, that'd be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 4.4+, you can do that with a single aggregation pipeline:

- match documents with both first and second tracking ID
- lookup an array of all documents with the same first tracking ID
- unwind the array
- consider the array elements as the root document
- match to eliminate any that have a second tracking ID
- set the desired status field
- [merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) the results with the original collection

```
{$match: {
          firstTrackingId: { $ne: "" },
          secondTrackingId: { $exists: true }
}},
{$lookup:{
    from: "Test",
    localField:"firstTrackingId",
    foreignField:"firstTrackingId",
    as:"matched"
}},
{$unwind:"$matched"},
{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$matched"}},
{$match:{secondTrackingId:{"$exists":false}}},
{$addFields:{status:"VOID"}},
{$merge: {into: "Test"}}
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you so much! $lookup is something I had looked into but was struggling to figure out how to get it to work in the same collection -- guess I was just overthinking it, as usual. This is working perfectly for me! I took out {$merge: "Test"} because it was giving me the following error: Value expected to be of type DOCUMENT is of unexpected type STRING. It seems to be working perfectly without that {$merge: "Test" line, though. Thank you again!

Comment: Yep, that was the wrong syntax, corrected now.  With the $merge stage, you won't need to run update separately